# Method Creates new instance

Tags: java, new-operator, object-reference

When a method returns an object, does that method automatically create a new instance of 
that object in memory?

For example:

In `Java` `BigInteger` `class` , I use the add method where `num1`, and `num2`, lets say, are `BigIntegers`.

`num1.add(num2);`

Then I reference it by the same type as in:

```
BigInteger a = num1.add(num2);
```

This works and gets the correct data. So the method will create a `new instance` of that object on the stack?

Just making sure I'm correct about my assumption.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, Wrapper classes are Immutable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bigInteger.add() does return a new instance, but not all methods do.

What usually returns new object instances that you may run into regularly are:

- Constructors
- Factorys/Builders
- methods operating on immutable objects

`BigInteger`'s [add method says that it returns a BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#add%28java.math.BigInteger%29), doesn't say a `new BigInteger`, but given that the [docs also state that BigInteger is immutable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), then you can know it's not returning the `this` object with a modification, so chances are that it's a new object (I suppose it's possible to be some cached object already representing that state, but even if it was, your usage of BigInteger wouldn't change.).

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

With your BigInteger example, it is returning a new instance of the object.

However with something like StringBuilder, you can do

```
stringBuilder.append("this").append("is").append("a").append("string");
```

and each .append(String) is returning the same original object, it just allows you to chain the calls together.